# Combine django tests and testcafe?

Tags: django, testing, frontend, backend

I'm experminenting testing of frontend with testcafe https://testcafe.io/documentation/402631/guides/overview/why-testcafe
and backend with django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests

If I start two separate shell:

```
 python ./manage.py test #backend

 testcafe chromium ./tests/testcafe.js  #frontend
```

The backend test run faster than the frontend.
I'd like to use the django test feature that create an empty database for each execution.
And django tests for backend, is there a way to make a combo of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's [`test` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/#test) is meant for running unit tests not integration tests.

If you want to easily setup a test server with an empty database Django has a [`testserver` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/#testserver) for that purpose. This command also allows you to load some data into the test database that is created using [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/fixtures/#fixtures-explanation). So you can start a testserver by running:

```
python ./manage.py testserver
```

Comment: thank you,  it need also at least one fixture,I've created the fixture with python manage.py dumpdata my_app > my_app/fixture.json and then added the path to testserver.